# Performance of UITableView reloadData, reloadSections:withRowAnimation: and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I build a test purpose app to test the performance of these three methods on reloading the table view.

[image]

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  TableViewSample
//
//  Created by Antonio081014 on 8/2/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Antonio081014.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *listOfCards;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        NSString *carName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Car%d", arc4random() % 15];
        [list addObject:carName];
    }
    self.listOfCards = list;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.selectedIndexPath = nil;

    UIBarButtonItem *table = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Table" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(reloadTable:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *section = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Section" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(reloadSection:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *indexPath = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"IndexPath" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(reloadRow:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[table, section, indexPath];
//    self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[table, section, indexPath];
}

- (void)reloadTable:(UIBarButtonItem *)barItem
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)reloadRow:(UIBarButtonItem *)barItem
{
    [self reloadRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath forBarButtonItem:barItem];
}

- (void)reloadSection:(UIBarButtonItem *)barItem
{
    [self reloadSectionAt:0 forBarButtonItem:barItem];
}

- (void)reloadRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barItem
{
    if (indexPath) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

- (void)reloadSectionAt:(NSUInteger)section forBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barItem
{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"Asking Number of Sections in TableView");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Asking Number of Rows in Section");
    return self.listOfCards.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *carName = self.listOfCards[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = carName;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"Did Select Cell %@", indexPath);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
    NSLog(@"Did Deselect Cell %@", indexPath);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Will Display Cell %@", indexPath);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Did End Display Cell %@", indexPath);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Did Highlight Cell %@", indexPath);
}

@end
```

Log when three methods called.

```
ReloadData
2015-08-03 11:00:51.556 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 11}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.558 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 10}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.559 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 9}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.560 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 8}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.560 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 7}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.560 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.561 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.561 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.562 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.563 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.563 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.564 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.564 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Sections in TableView
2015-08-03 11:00:51.565 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Rows in Section
2015-08-03 11:00:51.566 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.567 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.567 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.568 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.569 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.569 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.570 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.571 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 7}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.572 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 8}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.573 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 9}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.573 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 10}
2015-08-03 11:00:51.574 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 11}


ReloadSection
2015-08-03 11:02:21.641 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Sections in TableView
2015-08-03 11:02:21.642 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Sections in TableView
2015-08-03 11:02:21.643 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Rows in Section
2015-08-03 11:02:21.647 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.649 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.651 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.653 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.655 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.657 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.659 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.662 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 7}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.664 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 8}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.666 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 9}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.669 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 10}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.671 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 11}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.990 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.991 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.992 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.992 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.993 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.994 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.994 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.995 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 7}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.995 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 8}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.996 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 9}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.997 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 10}
2015-08-03 11:02:21.997 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 11}

ReloadRow
2015-08-03 11:03:00.012 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did Highlight Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-08-03 11:03:00.015 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did Select Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-08-03 11:03:00.907 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Sections in TableView
2015-08-03 11:03:00.908 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Sections in TableView
2015-08-03 11:03:00.909 TableViewSample[324:90811] Asking Number of Rows in Section
2015-08-03 11:03:00.910 TableViewSample[324:90811] Will Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-08-03 11:03:01.217 TableViewSample[324:90811] Did End Display Cell  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
```

So, from the log:
[UITableView reloadData] consumes 16ms.
[UITableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:] consumes 323ms.
[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] consumes 302ms.

Question:

- Why [UITableView reloadData] is more efficient than reloadingSections even there is only one section?
- Why reloadingRowsAtIndexPaths takes that much of time, what actually takes the time?
- What kind of tools could help me verify or debug similar problems? and helper link reference if any?
- Thanks.

Comment: `reloadData` doesn't have to (optionally) animate the reloading of individual cells.

Comment: (And I notice that you don't actually show us any of the code.)

Comment: @HotLicks, Sorry about the code, I tried to format it right, but with no luck. Can you check my source code while trying "Edit"? Thank you so much.

Comment: Select the code and click the `{}` button.  It's not rocket science.

Comment: The answer is because `reloadData` doesnt have any animation, unlike `reloadSections:withRowAnimation` and `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` which validates your animation before reloading the rows/cells of tableView and that also goes for collectionView.

Comment: @HotLicks, Thank you so much for such a good formatting and show me how to do it.

Comment: @0yeoj, is there any tool I could use help me verify it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrowsatindexpaths), apple said:

> Reloading a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new cell for that row. The table animates that new cell in as it animates the old row out.

it seems that, when you call `reloadrowsatindexpaths`, a new cell will be initialized for the animation, while `reloadData` as we already knew, will reuse the cell before.

I think it can explain the question.